# Number of objects in a ng-repeat that is filtered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I'm using angularjs in a site and there I have a search input that filters a list on a view. This list is displayed with a ng-repeat that has a filter from the search input:

The search input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Device Search" class="form-control hasclear" 
  ng-model="searchText"/>
```

And here the ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-click="openModal(device['device_id'], device)" 
  ng-repeat="device in devices | filter:searchText | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
```

As you see the filter in the ng-repeat has the filter that uses the searchText variable from the ng-model. I would like to know if it's possible to know how many objects were found when the user enters a text in the search input (How many devices the ng-repeat is displaying being filtered). Like: `0 devices were found`, `3 devices were found`...

Is there a way to display this information by the way I built this search?

Comment: I tried to find something here, but I couldn't. Should I delete it here? @isherwood

Comment: Not necessarily. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it outside of your `<tr>` tag, I would do it like this:

```
<tr ng-click="openModal(device['device_id'], device)" 
ng-repeat="device in filteredResults = (devices | filter:searchText | orderBy:predicate:reverse)">

{{filteredResults.length}} devices were found
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Based on Dave's response which is correct, you must assign a variable to the filtered result as so

```
<tr ng-click="openModal(device['device_id'], device)" 
ng-repeat="device in filtered_devices = (devices | filter:searchText | orderBy:predicate:reverse)">
```

Then, below your `tr` tag you can type:

```
<div>{{filtered_devices.length + ' devices were found'}}</div>
```

Plunkr example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/E88v6g7o7JKSMY54hMqS?p=preview)

Comment: this won't show filtered length, only total of original array

Comment: What am I missing? I have an example plunkr and it's working fine.

Comment: sure, edited version works but comment was made before editing

Answer (score 1):

with a filter like `filter:x as result` it stores the resultant collection on the variable `result`.

So you can do:

```
<tr ng-click="openModal(device['device_id'], device)" ng-repeat="device in devices | filter:searchText as filteredCollection | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
  <td><span>Filtered collection size: {{filteredCollection.length}}</span><td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a possibility with the properties:

- $last
- $index

something like:

```
<span ng-if="$last" > {{$index}} devices found </span>
```

documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat